# SharePoint IIS Configuration

Tags: sharepoint, sql-server-2016, windows-server-2016, iis-10, sharepoint-2016

I am new at SharePoint and have installed and configured everything, on the local machine (where SharePoint is installed), I connect with the PC name, and everything is working, I can access the front-end and the Central Administration.  I have a dns record that points to the ip of the computer. So on another machine, I use the url (intranet.domain.com) to connect.  Central Administration works (intranet.domain.com:12548) but when I try to access the front-end (Port 80 - intranet.domain.com) I get the following on my screen

[image: website view]

I presume something on my IIS is not setup correctly.

Any advise how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I need to create a new Web Application for the new Site Collection

Comment: Correct, to create your first Site collection, you have to create a new web application, 
as a best practice you have to create the least amount of web applications you can, and on your web applications create as many site collections you can...additionally you'll also might want to configure your AAM (alternate access mappings) to give your site the correct URL